# Vanishing of Gibbs Phenomenon in MatLab

Tags: signal, signal-processing, digital-communications, matlab, fourier

I was trying to represent a square wave with its Fourier series in Matlab.[image] But as I increased the number of terms in Fourier series expression, the Gibbs phenomenon vanished and the edges of the resultant square wave appeared to be curved a little.[image] Why does this happen in Matlab when it is impossible in theory?

This is my code:

```
clc;
close all;

f = 50;      %setting frequency as 50 Hz
t = 0:0.0001:3/f;

fourier = zeros(1,length(t));

for n = 1:1:50
   temp = ((2/(n*pi))*(1-cos(n*pi)))*sin(2*pi*n*f*t); %phase shifted by 'pi/2'
   fourier = temp + fourier;
end

%subplot(3,1,2);
plot(t,fourier);
title('When the number of terms is 200');
grid on;
```

Comment: What are number of terms in 2nd pic?

Comment: What is your sampling rate?  What would be the frequencies for the terms 50 and above?

Comment: Why are both graphs titled with 50 terms?

Comment: The analytical description of the situation shows the Gibbs phenomenon persisting to an arbitrary number of terms. Your discrete version does not. Therefore your discrete version does not model the analytical version faithfully enough to go to the number of terms you have. That much we can say with confidence without even having seen your code. If you want a better answer, we'll need to see your code.

Comment: Sorry for making the mistake, the number of terms in 2nd figure is 200. Frequency is 50 Hz for both the figures. And I am taking 10,000 samples in a second

Comment: Add MANY more points to your analog representation, and zoom in on a corner

Comment: My question is not "how to resolve it? ".  But "why does it happen? "